# Remote External Javascript Widget Execution

Tags: javascript

I am looking to implement an html widget on remote sites and through my research the consistent approach is to have the remote webmaster place a script in the head of the document that essentially places an external script tag in the head.

```
function requestContent( local ) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = CONTENT_URL;
  script.async = true;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Why can't I just have the webmaster insert the script tag directly?

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js">
```

Is it an async issue? I can't use the async param on the script tag because I need IE9 support, so is my only option the first method? Granted most of the articles I am finding on the topic are a bit outdated, which is the main reason for my question.

Comment: you can use the tag if you add the _async_ attrib, otherwise your server could slow down the remote site. tags added by JS have the same behavior benefits as adding _async_ to a hard-coded tag. note also that _async_ attribs don't work in old IE, which the remote site may or may not care about.

Comment: Ok so the async issue is the only reason for the former. That answers my question.

Comment: yup. do note that you don't need to over-specify _async_ on js-generated script tags, the behavior is the same with or without. you could have them use async and put the tag at the bottom of the body, where it won't stop rendering (but will still delay onload for old IE users, if anyone cares).